# First-child pseudo-class in css 2.1

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I don't know where to put pseudo class in this definition:

```
#recently_played_grid li img {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

I want to set margin-left to 0px just in a first child of the list. Should I do:

```
#recently_played_grid li:first-child img
```

?

It doesn't seem to work

Comment: Do you want the margin on the image within the first li, or the li itself?

Comment: You probably want `#recently_played_grid li img:first-child`. That will apply the styling to the first `img` child within that `li`.

Comment: Which element is the first child? That's where you should put the selector.

Comment: seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/58kVH/

Comment: Behavior of `first-child` is explained here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child Fiddle may shed more light on your problem

Comment: @Floris, thanks. But the problem still remains. I didn't tell you that my images are listed horizontally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you are looking for is to have **ALL** the images in the first li item then your code should work fine. If you are looking to have a margin on the first img child of every li then you'll have to change it to

```
#recently_played_grid li img:first-child

<ul>
    <li>
        <img />                    << Selects this, and
        <img />
        <img />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img />                     << Selects this, and
        <img />
        <img />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img />                     << Selects this
        <img />
        <img />
    </li>
</ul>
```

If you want only the **FIRST** img in the **FIRST** li then you should change it to

```
#recently_played_grid li:first-child img:first-child


<ul>
    <li>
        <img />                          << Selects only this
        <img />
        <img />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img />
        <img />
        <img />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img />
        <img />
        <img />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Further reading here http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-class-selectors

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to target. If it is the first `<li>` your selector should be:

```
#recently_played_grid li:first-child img { ... }
```

If you are trying to target the first image:

```
#recently_played_grid li img:first-child { ... }
```

The reason your margin isn't working may be that your element is set to be inline or you may be experiencing [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing). Try adding a background color or something to see if your selector is working. This should help you target the issue.

Also, if you are worried about cross-browser, older versions of IE don't support structural pseudo selectors. I usually use something like [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) as a polyfill.

Comment: `:first-child` selector has been supported in IE since IE7, as well as immediate sibling `+` combinator.

Comment: Margin collapse can never happen with a left margin.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to accomplish?

If you are trying to create an image gallery, and every image is in a list item, then what you might want to do instead is put a negative margin on the `<ul>` to counter the margin on the first `<li>`, and by extension every `<li>` that is in the first 'column'